# Automatic execute action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timeout

I want to automatic execution action in other controller at certain time.
I read more similar posts on this site, and all of them tell about whenever or delayed job.
But i don't understand how it works=(
This is an example of what i want.

```
def create
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@client = @user.clients.create(params[:client])
if @client.save
 redirect_to user_clients_path(@user)
      else
 render :action => 'new'
      end
Timeout(@client.event_time) 
    redirect_to :controller => :some_controller, action => some_action
end
```

Comment: You want the "create" action to be executed automatically at a certain time? If that's the case, it doesn't sound right cause params would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand what effect you want:

If what you want is a timeout action to take place if the user hasn't responded in a certain amount of time, then cleanest way to do it would be to write some javascript on the client side -- set a timer which fires an action if the timer expires, clear the timer if the user presses a button.

If what you want is to display a page for a few seconds after creating the Client and then switch to a new page, you can put a meta-refresh in the first page you display and have it automatically redirect to the desired page after @client.event_time seconds.